# Laravel 5 relationsheep between article and images

Tags: php, laravel, orm, image-uploading

Hi i'm new in Laravel and i've this simple problem. I have app where user can create some article and also can to upload main image for that article and it works perfect. I also want to give possibility to user to upload more images for his article. I already create model (ArticleImage) and add relationship between Article and ArticleImage. And i created form field for uploading multiple file inside the article form. But i don't know now how to tell laravel to save all names of these paths into database and store image inside the public/images folder, than later in views i can use these images. Do i need now to create ArticleImage controller and inside controller to write that function or i should do that inside Article controller inside store function. Tnx in advance for every help.
Here is link to github-repo(https://github.com/Dabizlja/Laravel-blog)

Answer (score 1):

If form sends input as array.

```
<input name="picures[]" />
```

In your ArticleController on save you can use a json type

```
$files=[];
$pictures = $request['pictures'];
if (count($pictures) > 0 && $pictures[0] != null) {  
        foreach ($pictures as $picture) { 
            $validator = Validator::make([$picture], ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png']);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return $validator->messages()->all();
            }

            $picture->move(public_path() . '/images/', $picture->getClientOriginalName());
            array_push($files, $picture->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }
   $article->images = json_encode($files);
```

To get it back in the view

```
<?php   
  foreach ( $images as $file) {
    echo  '<img src="'asset('/images/' . $file)'"/>';
  }
 ?>
```

In your controller on edit remember to decode the json

```
$files = json_decode($article->images);
```

To delete a picture you would have to go through the array and remove it the same way.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I can't remeber if `getClientOriginalName()` will also provide extension, please test and if not, concatenate `getClientOriginalExtension()` on save.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
$article->articleImages()->saveMany($images);
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: `$files = $request->file('images');
        $uploadcount = 0;
        foreach($files as $file) {
             $destinationPath = public_path('images/');
             $fname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
             $loc = $file->move($destinationPath, $fname);
             $uploadcount ++;
        }` i've this code in ArticleController but how i can tell from here hi take all names of these files and insert them inside the article_images table in field name. Do i need to do that inside ArticleImagesController?